# shop by brand name in magento

Tags: magento

This is brand.php file having directory local/Vilpjsc/brand/Block.I want the brand name with logo(image)  sholud display on home page .But I am getting the error i.e Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /var/www/magentodemo/app/code/local/Vilpjsc/Brand/Block/Brand.php on line 25

```
<?php

class Vilpjsc_Brand_Block_Brand extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
public function _prepareLayout() {
      return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

//Get Collection from Brand Controller
public function getBrand() {


    if (!$this->hasData('brand')) {

        $this->setData('brand', Mage::registry('brand'));

    }
    return $this->getData('brand');
}

//Get Brand Featured Collection
public function getFeaturedBrand() {

    return $this->getBrand()->getCollection()->setPageSize(12)->addFilter('status', '1');

}

public function resizeImage($img,$width=100, $height=60) {

    if (!file_exists("./media/brand/resized"))
        mkdir("./media/brand/resized", 0777);
    $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "brand" . DS . "resized" . DS . $width."x".$height.$img;
    if (!file_exists($imageResized) && file_exists("./media/brand/" . $img)) {
        $imageObj = new Varien_Image("./media/brand/" . $img);
        $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
        $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
        $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
        $imageObj->resize($width, $height);

        $imageObj->save($imageResized);
    }
    $newImageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."brand/resized/".$width."x".$height.$img;

    return $newImageUrl;
}

public function getNormalBrand() {

    return $this->getBrand()->getCollection()->addFilter('status', '0');
}

public function getBrandChar() {

    extract($this->getBrandKey());

    return $this->getBrand()->getCollection()->saveBrandcollection($char);
}

//Create Alphabet navigation
public function navigation() {
    extract($this->getBrandKey());
    $alphas = range('A', 'Z');
    $navigation = "";
    $digitClass = "";
    foreach ($alphas as $key) {
        if ($char == $key)
            $class_key = "current_char";
        else
            $class_key="";
        $navigation .= "<li class='key_item " . $class_key . "'><a href='" . Mage::getBaseUrl() . "brand/index/index/brand_key/" . $key . "'>" . $key . "</a></li>";
    }
    if ($char == "digit") {
        $digitClass = "current_char";
    } elseif ($char == "all")
        $allClass = "current_char";
    $navigation = "<li class='key_item " . $digitClass . "'><a href='" . Mage::getBaseUrl() . "brand/index/index/brand_key/digit'>#</a></li>" .
            $navigation;
    return $navigation;
}

//Get request for brand block
public function getBrandKey() {
    $brand_key = Mage::registry('brand_key');

    if ($brand_key) {
        $char = $brand_key->getParam('brand_key') ? $brand_key->getParam('brand_key') : 'A';
        $option_id = $brand_key->getParam('option_id') ? $brand_key->getParam('option_id') : '1';
        $brand = $brand_key->getParam('brand') ? $brand_key->getParam('brand') : 'Nike';
    } else {
        $char = 'digit';
        $option_id = '544';
         }
         return compact('char', 'option_id', 'brand');
         }
      }
```

Comment: where is the brand set? because you are getting the brand from registry `Mage::registry('brand')` but you don't say where is this brand set? (look for `Mage::register('brand'...)` )

Comment: I am really sorry because I am totally new in magento.I think u are asking about controller and block....In my controller that is as $brand = Mage::getModel("brand/brand"); and in my block that is above.

Comment: What's the extension you are using? you are using a custom extension and in the code mentioned you are using a variable that probably is not set...

Comment: I am using Shop_By_Brand_Vilpjsc-2.0.5_ready2paste But that is working for admin means I am getting images and able to upload images to data base.But for frontend that don't.I have got a featured brand option on admin manage categories option.Also If I'm

Comment: removing the code public function getFeaturedBrand() {
       
        return $this->getBrand()->getCollection()->setPageSize(12)->addFilter('status', '1');
        
    }  to   public function getFeaturedBrand() {
       
        return $this->getBrand();
        
    } I'm not getting the error and if I will replace to previous one I'm getting the images without error.If i will click home then same error.

Comment: that extension is Shop By Brand / Manufacturer - Free Extension

Comment: I am using the extension downloaded from the below url. please let know if you have any magento free extension having such type of functionality. Thanks in advance. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shop-by-brand-manufacturer-free-extension.html